# Como deixar os campos com o mesmo estilo?

Tags: android, android-layout

Eu não gosto de ficar repetindo código e acredito que há uma maneira de deixar, por exemplo, dois campos ou mais com o mesmo estilo de formatação:

Logo abaixo tenho dois `EditText` eles têm algo em comum, como as margens da esquerda e da direita e o topo.

Como eu poderia digitar, apenas uma vez estas margens, para esses campos e futuros campos que forem criados, sem ter que digitar em todos os campos esta mesma configurações de margens?

```
<EditText  
    android:id = "@+id/edfirstnumber" 
    android:layout_width = "match_parent" 
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginTop = "20dp" 
    android:layout_marginLeft = "10dp" 
    android:layout_marginRight = "10dp" 
    android:hint = "@string/campoNumerico" 
    android:inputType = "number" 
/>

<EditText  
    android:id = "@+id/edsegundnumber" 
    android:layout_width = "match_parent" 
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginTop = "20dp" 
    android:layout_marginLeft = "10dp" 
    android:layout_marginRight = "10dp" 
    android:hint = "@string/campoNumerico" 
    android:inputType = "number" 
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Procure sobre [estilos e temas](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) (styles and themes). Você poderá criar um estilo específico para o que quer e aplicá-lo a todos os elementos que deseja. Mais sobre o assunto, [clique aqui](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidStylesThemes/article.html).

Answer (score 2):

Você pode criar um `style` com todos os atributos em comum e usar ele no seu `EditText`.

Você teria no seu arquivo `styles.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CustomText" parent="@style/Text">
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#008</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Chamo atenção ao `parent="@style/Text"` porque se isso não for usado você acaba descaracterizando o `EditText`**

E no seu layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText
    style="@style/CustomText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello, World!" />
```

O Código foi retirado daqui: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource.html.